# Bool to bit in the C#

Tags: c#, binary, boolean, boolean-operations

We have two Boolean variables that I want to be like this:

```
b1      b2       bin  int
true ,  true =   11   (3)
false , true =   01   (2)
true ,  false =  10   (1)
false , false =  00   (0)
```

Comment: Check out `bitarray` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=netcore-3.1 or `BitVector` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Or bitflag enum.

Comment: You could just do `int i = (b2 ? 2 : 0) | (b1 ? 1 : 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitVector32` can do this.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32?view=netcore-3.1

```cs
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var b1 = false;
            var b2 = true;

            var bitvector = new BitVector32();
            bitvector[1] = b1;
            bitvector[2] = b2;

            var intValue = bitvector.Data;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But remember that the index takes a bit mask, so the indexes need to go up in powers of 2. `1, 2, 4, 8, 16` etc.

The masks can be generated by `1 << n`. Where `n` is the bit you want to access (0 indexed).

`BitVector32` also provides a `CreateMask` method to generate them.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.createmask?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Specialized_BitVector32_CreateMask